# Google Cloud SSL Certificate still provisioning after 24 hours

Tags: ssl-certificate, cloud, load-balancing

My Google Cloud (load balancer, certificate, etc.)configuration has all of the required steps completed but the certificate is still provisioning.

Comment: Im still facing this same issue can u tell in steps by steps how i can solve it plse

Comment: @MohdRashid , use the Google cloud tool instead of the console.

Comment: im not using both gcloud or console from GUI(GCP) i configure but still ssl is Provisioning after 72hrs gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The solution is to create a domain mapping and DNS record using the gcloud tool instead of Google Cloud Console.